# Why is this CSS navbar not completely at the top?

Tags: css, web, nav, navbar

Here's the code of the navbar:

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  }
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; }
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; }
```

As requested, here's the HTML of the navbar:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Shouldn't this make it be completely at the top since padding is zero? I'm new to webdesign... All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the top of what? There is no context to your question...

Comment: Pastebin your HTML if you could. Makes it easier to test :).

Comment: did you reset body margin ?

Comment: @NickR I need it to be completely at the top of the page, but there's a huge gap in between my browser's navigation toolbar and the navbar...

Comment: @GCyrillus How do I do that?

Comment: body {margin:0;} i made this an answer since it looks you did no nothing about it :)

Comment: Inspect the element in `Firebug` or equivalent, and see which elements have padding. You might need to add a reset stylesheet before your main one, or at least include one at the top of your CSS - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: With no jsfiddle, codepen or else where problem is shown , you'll get only the tip to make a reset

Comment: @Aslet http://jsfiddle.net/W5uDr/ - with `* selector` reset (Though you'll want the full reset css - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), works fine, and sits right at the top of the page.

Comment: @NickR I did that, and I've been changing all the paddings with firefox's style editor, but nothing seems to work...

Comment: @Aslet Create a Fiddle with all your CSS and HTML - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've done a reset at the top of your stylesheet to avoid browser defaults.

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

there are likely other reset snippets you will find on the web, but this alone should help.

Answer (score 2):

try a reset on body margin, else show us a test page:

```
body {margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're removing the margin and padding from the `body` and `html` tags:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

Always a good idea to use a CSS reset if you're not already.  It will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys, thanks for your help though.

The problem was in this piece of code I hadn't posted:

```
div.content{
        border: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
        background-color: #fff;
        max-width: 640px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2%;
        margin: 0px  auto;
    }
```

I had the margin set to something else other than zero.

Comment: so it was code missing but still margin reset. If all infos from start, you would have had right the away the answer. Good you figure it out with all this resets send to you :p

Answer (score 0):

if this

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

isn't helping, then there is another css messing with these ones.

Here is example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCNbX/)